# Defining function with parameters (str,n) that the index value "n" removes the character in that position?

Tags: python

Write a function that will accept two parameters: a string and an integer n. Return a new string
where the character at index n has been removed. If the value of n is invalid, return the original
string.

*This function will be called into "main" function*
Beginning python coder here and I am not the best at understanding how functions work.

my code --> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdVjC.png)

Comment: This is a homework wording. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Surely your class has a textbook that explains how functions work. We're not a tutoring service.

Comment: Hi yes, I have provided my code in the edited post. Like I said I am new to coding and if you have any recommendations to point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. I am also new to stack overflow so I do appreciate it :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go... 
and your code is not correct.

```py
def removeChar(str, pos):
    # str[:pos] gives string from index 0 upto pos (excluding pos)
    # str[post+1:] gives string from pos + 1 upto end
    return str[:pos] + str[pos+1:]

def main():
    print(removeChar("Hello", 2))

main()
```

Comment: Dude you shouldn't just do it for him

Comment: But here ya go an upvote

Answer (score 1):

To remove any character from a String, we have to create a new string since Strings are **immutable** in Python (unlike lists).

There are several ways to do so -

1. Using **Slicing** - This is the most common approach.

```py
s = 'ABCDE'
i = 2 
s = s[:i] + s[i+1:]
# s[:i] gives the characters in the string from index 0 to i-1 (excludes index i)
# s[i+1:] gives the characters in the string from index i+1 to end
print(s) # This will print ABDE
```

2. Converting to List - We can convert the string to a mutable list of characters. After removing the character at the specified index, we can convert it back to string.

```py
s = 'ABCDE'
i = 2 

l = list(s) # Convert to list
del(list[i]) # Deletes the character at index i from the list
s = "".join(l) # Converts the list back to string

print(s) # This will print ABDE
```

Now, let's discuss about your code :)

```py
def missingChar (str, n):
    str = ""  
    # str is taken as an argument for the function. If it is initialized to "", the purpose of taking it as an input to the function is not served
    index = str
    value = n
    # The above lines are unnecessary
    for index in str:  # Since, the value of the index at which the character should be removed is already given, a for loop is not needed
        index.pop(value) # pop() is a list method... So, it can't be used with strings
        return

# Create the main function that will be used throughout the HW
def main():
    missingChar("kitten",1) # The function call is perfect :)
    # If you want to print the output of the function 'missingChar', store the return value in a variable, and then print it or directly print it by calling the function inside print()

main()
```

Considering your approach, the following can be done -

```py
def missingChar (s, n):
    l = list(s)  # Convert to list
    l.pop(n)   # Use the pop() list method freely :)
    s = "".join(l)  # Convert the list to string
    return s

def main():
    result = missingChar("kitten",1)
    print(result)
    
    # OR
    # print(missingChar("kitten",1))
    
main()
```

Comment: yo nice explanation :)

Comment: I appreciate the responses and the explanation on the different ways this questions can be achieved. Definitely a learning lesson :) thank you!